How to make session variables pass between pages?
To start off, I have multiple webpages in express. I save a variable into a session in a post request, then it redirects to a different page. On that page, I attempt to access the variable. But it returns "Undefined". I checked the session ids on those 2 functions, they do not match up. This might be because the sessions could be local.
I expected the variable to be passed between the two functions securely. (There is no need to have a database all the variables are temporary.)

A standard example for the sessions in the express, go through it. Modify the below code according to your application.
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'your_secret_key', // Replace with a strong secret
    resave: false,             // Avoid resaving session if not modified
    saveUninitialized: true,   // Save new sessions even if they are not modified
    cookie: { secure: false }  // For development (set to true if using HTTPS)
}));

app.use(express.json());       // To handle JSON bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // To handle URL-encoded bodies

const PORT = 8080;

// Route to save variable to session and redirect
app.post('/save-to-session', (req, res) => {
    const { myVariable } = req.body;
    req.session.myVariable = myVariable;
    res.redirect('/next-page');
});

// Route to access the variable from session
app.get('/next-page', (req, res) => {
    const myVariable = req.session.myVariable;
    if (myVariable) {
        res.send(`The variable from session is: ${myVariable}`);
    } else {
        res.send('Variable not found in session');
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


Is the res.redirect required? Because i have tried without it, and it hasn't worked.
